# Is Code of methods for different object of same class present in executable?

Tags: c#

If I create an array of 10 objects of class A, will the object methods be present (in the assembly) 10 times for each object or just single instance of the method code which will work for the different data of the different objects?

Comment: Try a simple experiment.  Create a class with a couple of methods, instantiate one instance, and compile.  Note the size of the executable.  Then modify your program to create 1000 instances and recompile.

Comment: What happens if you create an array of some size selected by the user at runtime? Think about it.

Comment: There will only be one method defined in the assembly, at runtime there could be multiple versions if the class or method are generic.

Comment: At the time the executable is created, it's not even decidable how many objects will be created in the course of the execution.

Answer (score 3):

No, the code belongs to the *class*, and will only be represented once. The array and the objects don't even exist until execution time - given that the size of the array could vary, the executable file couldn't possibly contain the code duplicated "enough" times.

Bear in mind that the code itself stays the same for all objects - it would be pointless to duplicate the code even in memory, let alone in the file. (There are some cases where JITted code could potentially vary to take account of inlining differences between base classes and derived classes, but that doesn't happen with the Microsoft CLR as far as I'm aware.)

Answer (score 0):

Only one instance of the method will exist in the executable.  When the method is called it will be passed a pointer to the data members of the specific object you want to work on.